# Cannot implicitly convert type System.LinQ.IOrderedEnumerable to MyClassCollection. An implicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have following classes in my project.

```
[Serializable]
public class BaseEntityCollection<T> : List<T> where T : BaseEntity, new()
{

    protected BaseEntityCollection()
    {
    }

}

[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    protected BaseEntity()
    {
    }
}


public class MyClassCollection : BaseEntityCollection<MyClass>
{
}
```

---

### Problem Area

```
MyClassCollection objList = 
MyClassName.MyFunctionName().OrderByDescending(i => i.MyPropertyName);
```

### This line is giving compilation error.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type System.LinQ.IOrderedEnumerable<MyClass>
to MyClassCollection. An implicit conversion exists(are you missing a
cast?)
```

### EDIT

**I don't have the privilege to change the Architecture design.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear why you'd expect that to work, but you could use:

```
MyClassCollection objList = new MyClassCollection();
objList.AddRange(MyClassName.MyFunctionName()
                            .OrderByDescending(i => i.MyPropertyName));
```

Personally I dislike deriving new collections from `List<T>` in the first place, and also deriving non-generic classes from generic classes *just* to pin the type arguments, but if that's the architecture you've got to live with...

Answer (score 1):

```
var orderedItems = MyClassName.MyFunctionName().OrderByDescending(i => i.MyPropertyName);
MyClassCollection objList = new MyClassCollection(orderedItems);
```

The result of your expression when you add `OrderByDescending` is a framework class that implements `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, which cannot be implicitly converted to `MyClassCollection`. You could add an implicit conversion, or just pass in any `IEnumerable<T>` to a constructor that you would inherit from `List<T>`, as shown above.

Comment: There is no overloaded constructor. Still giving compilation error.

Comment: @Guest: Well how are you *expecting* it to create an instance of MyClassCollection?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Thanks for your presence. Actually I don't have the privilege to change the  architecture. So I cannot create an overload.

Comment: @Guest If you cannot feed the enumerable into a constructor and you are not being given a type of MyClassCollection you cannot ever create one in this manner. Basically you might have to resort to iterating the results and adding them manually...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create new collection, or sort the returned one? If it is later, then forget about `OrderByDescending` and LINQ in general and use [List.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) instead.

<strike>The problem is that calling OrderByDescending will create new internal LINQ object, that implements `IOrderedEnumerable`. You will then need to create some real collection like `List` or `Array`.</strike>

To solve your problem you should override IEnumerable construrcor in `BaseEntityCollection<t>` like:

```
public BaseEntityCollection(IEnumerable<T> items):base(items)
{
}
```

And call it like:

```
  MyClassCollection objList = new MyClassCollection(MyClassName.MyFunctionName().OrderByDescending(i => i.MyPropertyName));
```

But I would really question your whole design. You should read more about LINQ, before you start using it, because the way you try to use it is wrong.